# Name property for rules in CSS styles alternatives or how to contribute

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

We are using https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#json-output-format to ascertain what rules of a style created in Geoserver's style editor and that has rule names are defined at a specific zoom level and then proceed to issue getLegendGraphic calls for these specific rules to get Geoserver-rendered style rule images that fit better in a client than a variable size getLegendGraphic image for a theme layer (multiple rules for a given zoom level).

From the above linked documentation that isn't the point of the json representation of a style however it works well for styles created as SLDs where the rules have names. It does not work for styles created via the CSS extension for they have no "handles", which is to say names, so a standard getLegendGraphic call with a `rule=` param cannot be issued for such styles as far as I know.

Is there another way of getting specific Geoserver rendered style rule images for CSS created styles? (Or would we need to interpret the json style representation and render it in the client). If no other way, where would I look if we were open to trying to contribute to certain development?

Fyi it was discussed here https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/36050785/ and I tried creating a followup thread in the Geoserver users mailinglist about a year ago (there were no replies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules in CSS have a title, but not a name. In theory, a name could be given to rules too, using a comment tag like for title.

For the normal cascading mechanism, that would require combining names just like titles are combined, as SLD rules are often created merging multiple CSS rules. Even disabling cascading, nesting would have to be taken into account.

That said, doable but requires code changes, mostly located in this GeoTools class:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/029dc5c8ccc503de3cfd7f4d1c939d8056c260c4/modules/unsupported/css/src/main/java/org/geotools/styling/css/CssTranslator.java#L998